# Differentiating an integral where upper bound is in terms of x

Tags: calculus

> Suppose that:
>   $$F(x)=\int_{-2}^{x e^x} \sin t^2 dt.$$
>   Find the value of $\frac{dF}{dx}$ when $x=2$, showing your work clearly.

Just checking to see if my working is okay!

Let $ u = xe^x,$

\begin{align*} \frac{dF}{dx} &= \frac{dF}{du} \times \frac{du}{dx}, \\
&=  \sin (u^2) \times (e^x + xe^x). \end{align*}

Therefore at $ x=2$ we have:

$\sin\left((2e^2)^2\right)\times (e^2 + 2e^2)$

Comment: I would change  $sin(2e^2)^2 * (e^2 + 2e^2)$ to $ \sin\left( (2e^2)^2 \right) \cdot (e^2 + 2e^2)$ just to make it a little clearer. Note, too, that by writing `\sin` instead of `sin`, you get a nice non-italic sine function, and that it's nice to use `\cdot` for multiplication rather than an asterisk (which is more appropriate in (some) programming than in math).

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Thanks! @ParclyTaxel  I evaluated my expression when x =2 to obtain (approx.) -22.14. this seems a little odd ?

Comment: @JohnHughes i see, noted for next time!

Comment: $4e^4/pi\approx 69.5\pi=34(2\pi) + \frac32\pi,$ which implies $\sin(t^2)$ is near its minimum value (which is negative) when $t = 2e^2,$ which implies that its integral is decreasing. Also, since the function $\sin((xe^x)^2)$ oscillates very rapidly near $x=2,$ it is not too surprising to see that the integral is decreasing rapidly.